# Automatically set starting line number from last one in Jekyll highlight code blocks

Tags: jekyll, highlight, line-numbers

In my Jekyll3 blog, I use the `highlight` Liquid Tag to display syntax-highlighted code with fine line numbering. This is accomplished by doing:

```
{% highlight python linenos %}
# some code goes here
{% endhighlight %}
```

Now I often put several code blocks such as this in any given post. Let's suppose that the first code block has N lines, how can I have the second code block to start at line number (N+1)?

**I know this can be done manually** by providing the starting line value to the option `startinline` on the `highlight` tag, but I would want to accomplish this **automatically**.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this automatically, neither with Pygments nor with Rouge. You can only do it manually, sorry.